# How to read content between tags of asp.net server control

Tags: asp.net, custom-server-controls, servercontrols

I'm writing an asp.net server side control which has a few short parameters passed into it, but also the need to allow a large piece of custom HTML code to be supplied.

The easiest way of doing so I thought was to allow to be specified between the tags of the server control, like so:

```
<MyControl:Example Runat="server" Id="myControl" Message="This is a message">
  <p>This is a long piece of HTML a few dozen lines long...</p>
</MyControl>
```

**How can I access the text between the tags from inside my custom server control?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a templated control:

```
<MyControl:Example Runat="server" Id="myControl" Message="This is a message"> 
  <HtmlContent><p>This is a long piece of HTML a few dozen lines long...</p></HtmlContent>
</MyControl>
```

Where `HtmlContent` is your template.  Generally when I need templates, I simply use PlaceHolder instead.

```
public class MyControl : CompositeControl 
{ 
    [TemplateContainer(typeof(PlaceHolder))] 
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)] 
    public PlaceHolder HtmlContent { get; set; } 

    ... render stuff

}
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36574bf6.aspx)'s an example on MSDN:

Comment: Thanks for this @chris-gessler - I hoping that someone would be able to provide a short inline example, the templated control documentation and examples seem to be targeted at more advanced uses.

Comment: @PeterBridger - server controls are somewhat advanced and may take a few days of research, trial & error, etc.. Start off with a simple one, look at a bunch of examples and research what each item does in the examples so you have a better understanding of how it all works.  I suggest deriving from CompositeControl and using PlaceHolder for your template to start off.  You can get more advanced as your knowledge improves.  Just wait until you want to bind it to a datasource :)